# Load a view using AJAX in ASP.NET 3 RAZR

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

When using MVC you are calling actions that then load a view and a parent layout/masterpage. When you wish to load a view using AJAX though and then stick that content say inside a div with an id of content you would end up loading all the layout and stuff as well as you are just calling the action.

How do I get around this? Is their some way to say if calling this action using AJAX then don't bother with the layout and just shove the view inside the div?

Any code examples would be much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your ajax response HTML you can select only the div or elements you want to display

lets suppose your ajax calls looks like this:-

```
$.ajax(
   url: 'some_url',
   success:function(responseHtml){
     $('.div-on-current-page').html( $(responseHtml).find('.div-inside-response') ); 
   });
```

just give your response HTML to jquery `$(responseHtml)` and select the content you want `$(responseHtml).find('.div-inside-response')` and set it in your current page div

`$('.div-on-current-page').html( $(responseHtml).find('.div-inside-response') );`.

Answer (score 1):

ajax request

```
$.ajax({
   url: '/controller/action',
   type:'POST',
   success:function(data){ // data will contain the html rendered by partial view
     $('#someDivID').html(data);  
   }
  });
```

your ActionResult will look like

```
public ActionResult ActionName()
{
//some code 
return PartialView();
 //or
 // return View();
}
```

Comment: Ah right cool :) just though it might require the use of a partial to do what I'm wanting.

Comment: But that in reality gives you an PartialViewResult, and you don't use that in javascript

Answer (score 0):

**Process:** You need to do a ajax call to one action which give you a view you want in a string, bellow you can see the different methods you need to take what you o want.

'RenderPartialViewToString' method convert the view in a string:

```
    public static string RenderPartialViewToString<T>(
        ControllerContext context,
        string partialViewName,
        T model,
        TempDataDictionary tempData)
    {
        ViewEngineResult result = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(context, partialViewName);

        if (result.View != null)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(sb))
            {
                using (HtmlTextWriter output = new HtmlTextWriter(sw))
                {
                    ViewContext viewContext = new ViewContext(context, result.View, new ViewDataDictionary<T>(model), tempData, output);
                    result.View.Render(viewContext, output);
                }
            }

            return sb.ToString();
        }

        return String.Empty;
    }
```

In your action, call 'RenderPartialViewToString' method:

```
    public ActionResult ActionName(ActionParameters)
    {
          return Json(RenderPartialViewToString(this.ControllerContext, "ViewName", model, tempDict), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

In Javascript make something like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/controllerName/actionName',
    success:function(result){
        $('div#someID').html(result);  
    }
});
```